# Conditional Rendering not working React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AuthNavigator from "./app/navigation/AuthNavigator";
import Splash from "./app/screen/splash";
import AppNavigator from "./app/navigation/AppNavigator";
import { auth } from "./app/authentication/Firebase";

export default function App() {
  const [isSplashVisible, setIsSplashVisible] = useState(true);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setIsLoggedIn(!!user);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsSplashVisible(false);
      }, 2000); 
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  if (isSplashVisible) {
    return <Splash />;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isLoggedIn ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

My expo app is not working, when I run the app it is stuck in same white screen, I have tried reload and stuff but it doesn't work, and if I make some import error it still shows error , but the web app works perfectly, pressing W

Comment: "it still shows error" Please edit your question to show the exact error message and stack trace that you get.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the the function `auth.onAuthStateChanged` again, put log on this